# How to find the AS code in FLA file

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a .FLA file that doesn't have AS files attached, but I think that is inside of him, the question is How can I edit those AS that is inside of this .FLA file if I can't open it, maybe decompile?

ps: this .FLA is maded by other programmer who gived me only the .FLA and .SWC FILES, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Mr.HellCoder..

Try this Press, Alt + F3 on your keyboard, the window explorer will appear.

You will find where is AS file..

Good Luck !

Comment: unfotunately i didn't find any code inside of those movieclips that i found by alt + F3

Answer (score 0):

Look at the library symbols and see if there is a Base Class defined and look at the File's Actionscript setting to see if there is a Document Class defined.

Answer (score 0):

HellCoder..

If you not find actionscript by clicking f9 or Alt+f3, that fla file has remote XML. I mean your fla's swf movie will run while internet connect otherwise it wont run. Just checking this, disconnect your internet and run your swf movie. if it wont run. You cant see that as file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the library right click something and press edit class